# Return back to initiating activity after sending email in android

Tags: android, android-activity

I want to return back to the initiating activity after sending email by invoking email client in android. But it is not working at all.
I have tried the below code.

```
try {
          path = android.provider.MediaStore.Images.Media.insertImage(
              getContentResolver(), returnedBitmap, "diploma.png", null);
          Uri diplomaUri = Uri.parse(path);         
          //send email with the above generated image as attachment
          final Intent emailIntent2 = 
                 new Intent(android.content.Intent.ACTION_SEND);
          emailIntent2.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_SUBJECT,
                                "Potty Diploma for Teddy");
          emailIntent2.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_TEXT, Html.fromHtml(""));
          emailIntent2.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_STREAM, diplomaUri);
          emailIntent2.setType("image/png");
          startActivityForResult(Intent.createChooser(emailIntent2, "Email:"), 
                                 EMAIL_SUCCESS);
      } catch(Exception e) {
          final AlertDialog.Builder builder = 
                new AlertDialog.Builder(v.getContext());
       builder.setTitle("Device Media Access");
       builder.setMessage("Failed to access media store of the device");
       builder.setCancelable(false);
       builder.setPositiveButton("OK", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
        public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {
         dialog.cancel();
        }
       });
       AlertDialog alert = builder.create();
       alert.show();
         }


@Override
    public void onActivityResult(int reqCode, int resultCode, Intent data){
     super.onActivityResult(reqCode, resultCode, data);
        switch(reqCode){
          case (EMAIL_SUCCESS):
            if (resultCode == RESULT_OK){
             Intent myIntent = new Intent(Progress.this, iGoPotty.class);
      myIntent.putExtra("tab_id", 2);
      startActivity(myIntent);
            }
        }
    }
```

Comment: @user525004: "I want to return back to the initiating activity after sending email by invoking email client in android." -- what do you think this means?

Comment: The control is going to the home screen after sending the email. It should come back to my application so that the user can continue interacting with my application.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It seems like you're trying to create a new intent to get back to your initial activity? why not just `setResult()` and `finish()` in `onActivityResult()`? I can't really see what you're trying to do without either some more code or a little more information on your part. I'm assuming you're calling `setResult()`, and `finish()`, properly within your email activity. This is then "being" caught here in `onActivityResult()`? For one, have you set a breakpoint and stepped through to see if you're getting any result whatsoever? If so, what is firing and what isn't? If everything is firing is your `myIntent != null`, might be scoping issue?

Comment: hi do u have any sample code for returning to activity after sending mail.I am struck on it.

Answer (score 0):

Try to add flag (see below) to get result back from email client:

> intent.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_FORWARD_RESULT);

This way you will get back to your activity.